# GNU Screen and Mac Terminal interaction woes

Tags: macos, terminal, gnu-screen

Setup:  OSX 10.6 Terminal.app with multiple tabs, one of which ssh's into a machine that has a running GNU Screen instance.   That screen instance has (among other things) and irssi session, bash shells.  (other details:  my screen key is ^-o)

How can I make sure *everything* works 'right'

Among the problems I have seen:

- tab, delete, others causing 'Wuff--Wuff', fixed by setting term=screen during the initial screen creation (http://droptips.com/wuff-wuff-from-mac-os-x-to-a-screen-session-on-linux)
- up and down arrows, not working right within irssi (fixed by option cursor down to \033[6~ in Terminal.app > keyboard)
- when $TERM is set to 'screen' my screen bar loses color... fixed by adding 'export TERM=xterm-color' to .bashrc on the foreign machines.

In short, it feels like a hydra!  Every time I fix something, something new comes up!  What is the 'right' solution for all this?  Switch to iTerm.app?

I would like

- all the keys to work in the 'normal' way... as they would in say 'putty' or similar, including during less and the like.
- all the window sizes to work right.  'reset' and screen '^-a W' should Do The Right Thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own, but no help seems forthcoming :)

```
Terminal > settings > advanced > declare as 'dtterm'
```

seems to be a good solution.   Or at least more consistently better than xterm-color, or TERM=screen.

With this, all four arrow keys and backspace work in Vim, Less.

Still broken:  ctrl-a-[ (gnu screen buffer) up and down seem borked, alas.